# very ample divisors on curves using Riemann Roch Spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves, projective-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a projective non-singular irreducible curve, let $D$ be a divisor on $C$. Suppose the Riemann-Roch Space is $L(D)=\langle f_1,...,f_n\rangle$.
Define $\phi_D:C\to \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ by $\phi_D(P)=(f_1(P):...,f_n(P))$. We say that $D$ is very ample if $\phi_D$ is an embedding.

Suppose $P\neq Q\in C$, $\phi_D(P)=(1:0:...:0),\phi_D(Q)=(0:1:...:0)$. I need to show that if $D$ is very ample, then $L(D-P)\neq L(D)$. I'm not sure how to go about that.

Some literatures incorporate a base point free property to the definition of very ample, but I don't have such a definition in this case.

Since $f_1$ achieves minimum order at $P$ across all $f\in L(D)$, is it true that $f_1\notin L(D-P)$? How to show this?

It is clear that $f_1\notin L(D-P)\iff L(D-P)\neq L(D)$, but I'm not sure how to prove either side of this equivalence.

Comment: The way you've written things with $P$ mapping to $(1:0:\cdots: 0)$ implies that $f_1(P) \ne 0$, which immediately implies $f_1 \not \in L(D - P)$ since all elements of that space vanish at $P$. Since there is an element of $L(D)$ which does not lie in $L(D-P)$, these spaces are different.

Comment: I don't see why that is true unless $D$ is effective.

Comment: Are you familiar with the equivalence $D$ effective iff $L(D) \ne 0$? I should be specific: $D$ is an effective divisor *class*. Effective classes can have non-effective representatives, but this whole question is really about divisor classes anyway, so the fact that we have a map at all is enough.

Comment: I see. $D$ itself need not be effective, but it is linearly equivalent to one of the same degree, so we can assume $D$ is effective WLOG. By an earlier exercise, the isomorphism property of $\phi_D$ is invariant under linear equivalence. Correct?

Comment: Even if $D$ is effective I don't see why functions in $L(D-P)$ vanish at $P$. For example if $D=2P$, then $D-P=P$, but $ord_P(f_1)=0$, so $f_1$ is in both.

Comment: Ahh, fair enough. In this situation you work with the same idea; namely that there is a function in $L(2P)$ which has a double pole at $p$. This function is therefore not in $L(P)$, the space of functions with at most *simple* poles at $P$.

Comment: The fundamental point is that there is a function realizing the minimal order that is excluded when we subtract $P$ (thereby raising the minimal order that a function in the RR space can have); we just have to talk about zeroes vs. poles depending on tje sign of the order.

Comment: Yes I know that part about the minimal order. The problem is do ANY functions disappear at all upon subtracting $P$?

Comment: This is easier to discuss without coordinates: consider the dual projective space $\mathbb P := \mathbb PL(D)^\vee$ of codimension $1$-subspaces in $L(D)$. We embed $C$ in $\mathbb P$ by sending the point $P \in C$ to the codimension $1$ subspace $L(D-P)$. If no functions disappear after subtracting $P$, we get the whole space instead of a subspace hence this map is undefined at $P$. But since $D$ is very ample and the map *is* defined, the result follows. This argument feels like cheating to me, but what you are showing is that very ample implies base point free, which *should* be obvious.

Comment: I figured it out. There is a "Moving Lemma" in Shaferevich that allows me to move the support of $D$ away form $P$. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that your complete linear system $|D|$ has base point, define the divisor
$$
F=\min_{E\in |D|} E
$$

Exercise: $|D-F|$ is base point free and $L(D)=L(D-F)$.

So we always can suppose that $|D|$ is base point free. In this case we can solve this with some propertys of the map $\phi_D$, for example $L(D-P)=L(D)$ implies that $P$ is base point of the complete linear system $|D|$.

Rmk: I think that for a good definition of very ample divisor it's necessary request that the complete linear system associated to this divisor is without base point.

Comment: I know that I can keep subtracting out base points to get to be base point free. I'm given an arbitrary divisor to work with so I can't just change it like that. Also we don't use linear systems, only RR spaces and order of functions. If it wasn't for looking up other literatures, I wouldn't know about complete linear systems

Comment: I'm in a beginner algebraic geometry course. We don't learn sheafs, global section, mereomorphic functions, etc. just a heads up.

Comment: using your notation, how do I know that, if $\phi_D=\phi_{D-F}$ is an isomorphism, then necessarily, $F=0$? Or it that even true?

Comment: $\phi_D$ is not equals to $\phi_{D-F}$ necessarily.